# Which scope of variables changes the state of the contract?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation

I had been reading about the state of a smart contract. [Here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html)

It also gives a small example of a contract.

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Here we have a variable storedData and if we want to set it, a transaction with x is send and the state of the contract changes. As far as I understood it correct it is not necessary to send a transaction to read storedData. I can perform a local call.

Now what about the following contract:

```
contract SimpleStorage {

    function set(uint x) {
        uint storedData = x;
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

storedData is now within the function and saves the content but will this change the state of the contract? Do I have to send a transaction to call this function or is a local call enough?

From my programming knowledge I would say not but I am not sure when it comes to smart contracts :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the first example and the second is that in the first, `storedData` is located in the contract's *storage*, while in the second the `uint` is a *memory* variable. Storage persists across transactions, memory does not. Thus, you are correct.

Comment: Could I call the second example locally or does it also have to be a transaction to invoke the function?

Comment: @Donut It needs to be transacted for the network to verify the change is allowed.

Comment: That's not true, if you send it as a transaction it will not return anything useful. Calling it locally will just return what you input. Nothing in the second example is stateful anyway